# Trying to print the frequency of integers in an array

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out the frequency of each integer in an array

```
import java.util.*;
public class NumFrequency {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter the amount of numbers your going to input, up to 50");
      int num = input.nextInt();
      int array[] = new int[num];

      System.out.println("Enter the "+ num + " numbers now.");

      for (int i=0 ; i<array.length; i++) {
          array[i] = input.nextInt();
      }

      System.out.println("array created");
      printArray(array);


    }

    public static void printArray(int arr[]){
        int n = arr.length;

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
    }
    private static int[] intFreqArray = new int[51];
    public static void FreqOfInt(int[] array, int num) {
        for (int eachInt : array) {
            intFreqArray[eachInt]++;
        }

        for (int m = 0; m<intFreqArray.length; m++) {
            if (intFreqArray[m] > 1) {
                System.out.println(m+ " occurs " + intFreqArray[m] + " times.");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It'll print out the array created by the user but nothing after that I'm lost as to why it wont print out the last part.

Comment: call `FreqOfInt` in `main`?

Comment: you would do well to follow java naming conventions: name methods with a leading lowercase letter, ie `freqOfInt` not `FreqOfInt`

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `FreqOfInt` before you print.

Note that we normally use lower case letters for the names of Java methods.

Answer (score 3):

In `main`, the last method call is to `printArray`, but you never call `FreqOfInt`.  That's why that output doesn't show up.

Call it after calling `printArray`.